# Adding "remember my password" in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, remember-me

I want to add an option 'Remember My Password' in Login Page of Drupal 6. Is there any module for this ?

Is there any drupal module which remembers user's name and password on login page and auto-fill fields when user comes back after signout ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for the [Remember me](http://drupal.org/project/remember_me) module?